# Why was my account banned after posting a valid answer?

Tags: support, post-ban

I gave the answer shown below to a question about a bug in the keyboard of an iOS UIWebView. I had put a link to my blog post containing a couple of other common answers to the question, as this question has had different answers for different users. I would not have done this if I hadn't seen this before on SO, and if there had been something against it in the FAQ (note that this answer is not simply a link, but a complete answer including a link which the user doesn't have to visit to implement the fix).

I created this new answer because it is fundamentally different from any other answer, and because discovering it was such a pain that I thought others would appreciate the feedback on old articles that I had searched when I was trying to solve the error. I think it's articulate and concise enough. My response was deleted and my account was banned from posting. It's not important to me that I link to my article. I would still like to post my answer, and I don't see what's so bad about it.

> The solution mentioned here didn't work for me. I had a persistent
>   error that seemed to be an issue with iOS, or at least my build
>   settings. I came up with a workaround. If you're still stuck like I
>   was, try this (the link was here). I think it will work.
>
> Put this into your web view's delegate:
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)v shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)r
> ```
>
> navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)t {
>
> ```
>   NSString *requestString = [[r URL] absoluteString];
>
>   if ([requestString hasPrefix: @"yourURLPrefix:"] ) {
>       if ([requestString hasPrefix: @"yourURLPrefix:keyboardFix"] ) {
>           //if your webview is a subview of a UIWindow, as is often the case, use self.superview as yourWindow
>           [yourWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
>       }
> }
> ```
>
> Put this into the onFocus event handler of any input element you need
>   to reliably bring up the keyboard:
>
> ```
> document.location = "yourURLPrefix:keyboardFix";
> ```
>
> Or, if you want to add the event handler programmatically from the
>   native code
>
> ```
> [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('yourTextInput').onfocus = function(e) {document.location = 'yourURLPrefix:keyboardFix';};"];
> ```

Comment: I have a hunch that this ban wasn't caused due to the answer, which looks fine.  You're not specific about what kind of ban either - is it a question/answer ban, or an account ban?

Comment: question/answer ban, i think ("Sorry, we are no longer accepting ..."). I posted the same answer many times on different questions, modifying it for context, because it was a valid answer to several questions. Could that be it? Thanks.

Comment: That certainly can be it. If you only made a small number of modifications and posted it on many questions without restraint - say on _any_ question that are applicable, whether they have answers or not. Also - are there any links in the answer? Specifically links that can be construed as self-promotional?

Comment: Oh, definitely. From my question: "I had put a link to my blog post containing a couple of other common answers to the question." I've seen some other articles linked on stack overflow, and I thought that forgoing the part where I create a fake-ish account and pretend not to be affiliated with the article would at least not get me banned if the article was still a valid piece of helpful information. Perhaps that was unwise, but, baby, my aim was true. I didn't want to lie to you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I deleted the answer.

What you neglected to mention is that this wasn't the only answer that you posted.  As a matter of fact, after five months of inactivity, you decided to post this answer *word for word a total of six times*.

Basically, you're spamming the site, so I deleted that answer, and all the others that you're copy-pasting throughout the site.

At some point, I assume the answer-ban kicked in because you've had so many answers deleted.

That said, you should really tailor each of your answers to the questions you want to answer.  Also, if you feel you need to place at least six links a day to your site on Stack Overflow, [then you're probably in the wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Thanks for this. The reason I was copy-pasting my stuff was to answer all the questions I had been digging through in the past, which are essentially the same. I'll just flag the other questions as duplicates. And I promise I'll never copy-paste anything again. And if I do, I'll superficially edit the content each time.

Comment: There. I chose your answer. I won't put the link in my answer, nor will I post multiple answers - instead, I'll flag duplicate questions as duplicate. You should let me answer the question, though, or I'm going to start doubting this whole "friendly ghost" facade you put on.

Comment: @user1217029 If they are duplicates, then flag them as duplicates.  If they are indeed duplicates then put *one* answer on the canonical reference.  Also, don't make superficial edits, make edits to directly answer the question as it's been asked.  Finally, linking to your content is OK, but the answer should stand on it's own without the link, and if all you're doing is exposing the link, then you're probably in the wrong place.

Comment: When someone else encounters the error I encountered, can't solve it for as long as I couldn't, and goes completely nuts because they can't find my elegant, versatile answer, that blood will be on your hands. You will have to write that poor guy's mother a letter telling her why he's licking poop off his fingers in a padded cell.

Comment: @user1217029 You're bordering on what we call "not being nice".  I recommend reigning it in a little bit.

Comment: You've got nothing left to threaten me with because YOU'VE TAKEN EVERYTHING FROM ME.
especially my answer privileges

Comment: @user1217029 poke around on meta a little bit and find out how the site works.  While I deleted your answers, you took the privilege away from yourself.  It's one you can easily get back, you just have to provide better quality content and respect more of the rules in place.

Comment: @user1217029 - I took a look at this, as did Kev, and we found that two of the questions really were duplicates of an earlier one, so we closed those to point at that question. I undeleted your answer there, because it was a good solution to that particular problem, and Kev undeleted your answer to one of the other questions which was close, but a slightly different problem. Two of the questions seemed to be unrelated issues with a similar title, and your answer didn't seem to apply to those, so I left those deleted. You've now received a couple of votes on these, so the ban might be lifted.

Answer (score 10):

The problem here is that you were spamming some fairly old posts with the same copy and paste answer. This is the wrong thing to do.

You should post your answer against one question where you think your answer provides a solution, then if you think your solution applies to other unanswered questions of a similar nature then flag them as a duplicate.

Hunting down questions (which is what you appear to have done) for the purpose of slapping in the same boilerplate answer isn't considered good etiquette on our site.

Because we had to delete these boilerplate answers this has probably tripped the answer and possibly the new question ban.

Comment: Thanks for this. The reason I was copy-pasting my stuff was to answer all the questions I had been digging through in the past, which are essentially the same. I'll just flag the other questions as duplicates. And I promise I'll never copy-paste anything again.

Comment: Lol, copy comment. Not that it's not OK, but it is annoying to see the same comment on every single answer.

Answer (score 9):

I'm guessing a bit here, but as far as I understand you the answer contained a link to somewhere (your blog?) and was posted in a short timeframe to several old questions.

This is a pattern that is often seen with users that try to promote their own site excessively. They find some roughly related content and post answers that link to their site to all of them.

This is a pattern we've seen countless times here, and if a moderator thought you were using your answer mostly to promote your own site, that would be reason enough to delete all these posts and suspend you. You should have received a moderator message with an explanation of that suspension (if it wasn't the automatic ban, which is a whole other subject).

I can't really say if the suspension was deserved in this case, I don't know if your post actually answered the questions where you posted it. One point in your favor would be that the answer seems to contain a full solution, and not just a link. But I'd be generally very careful with copy-pasting answers to a lot of questions.

Comment: Thanks for this. The reason I was copy-pasting my stuff was to answer all the questions I had been digging through in the past, which are essentially the same. I'll just flag the other questions as duplicates. And I promise I'll never copy-paste anything again.